# Bash pipe consumption order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Suppose I have a couple Bash scripts written up, and they are intended to be used with pipes like such for easy composability:

`$ ./foo.sh /tmp/{one,two} | ... <potentially more pipes here, e.g. grep> ... | ./bar.sh`

where `foo.sh` will

1. `mkdir` the folders `/tmp/one` and `/tmp/two`, and
2. `echo` each created folder path as a new line to stdout

and `bar.sh` is supposed to

1. Take each line of its STDIN (say, as `$folder`)
2. `sleep` 2 seconds, to simulate a small time delay
3. Touch a file in `$folder/bar.txt`

tl;dr: My `foo.sh` stdout production will almost always outpace the consumption rate of `bar.sh`.

The thing is, I don't want my `mkdir /tmp/two` command in `foo.sh` to happen until my `bar.sh` to have finished consuming the stdin that correspond to the `mkdir /tmp/one` echo output. In other words, the order of things I would like to happen should look like:

1. `foo.sh`: `mkdir /tmp/one`
2. `bar.sh`: `touch /tmp/one/bar.txt` (with sleeping)
3. `foo.sh`: `mkdir /tmp/two`
4. `bar.sh`: `touch /tmp/two/bar.txt` (with sleeping)

I understand that Bash pipe may not be the solution to solve the problem here. My question is, is this still somehow achievable? Feel free to add any use of additional pipes or commands necessary to get the ordering right (`xargs` comes to mind).

Comment: @andlrc: ok. can you elaborate on how you would solve it without that section? Or how it presents as the problem?

Comment: If you really, truly need lockstep behavior, you can use a coproc or an extra named pipe and let foo.sh wait until signaled to continue

Comment: @thatotherguy do you mind to give some additional explanations on how to use a coproc to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foo.sh` knows what `bar.sh` is doing, it can simply watch for the appropriate file:

```
mkdir /tmp/one
# Polling isn't great, but can be replaced with OS-specific tools
# like inotify
until [[ -f /tmp/one/bar.txt ]]; do
    sleep 1
done
mkdir /tmp/two
# etc
```

This doesn't require `bar.sh` to have any special knowledge of `foo.sh`. Alternatively, you reverse who knows about whom, and have `foo.sh` simply block on a fixed resource:

```
mkdir /tmp/one
touch /tmp/barrier
while [[ -f /tmp/barrier ]]; do
    sleep 1
done
mkdir /tmp/two
```

Now it is the responsibility of `bar.sh` to know about `/tmp/barrier` and to remove it after creating `/tmp/one/bar.txt`.

Either way, one needs some knowledge about the other in order to know how to send a signal.

Comment: Yea I hear you @chepner. However it would essentially render my `foo.sh` script not useful in standalone cases really. The assumption of "assuming `foo.sh` knows what `bar.sh` is doing" part is really the crux of the solve I am after. I would like to see if it is possible to not have this knowledge in an explicit way.